# How we can get android phone's Manufacturing Date, Refurbished check by programmatically?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app which is about showing Android phone's hardware and software information such as Internal storage, Screen size, IMEI, Rootes etc.
I got stuck in getting some information such as Manufacturing Date, Refurbished check, Phone Color, Headset connect counter, Charger connect counter and also some sensor health information such as InfraRed, Ant+, Radio Transmitter.

Is there any way to get above all things information?

I have find one application similar to my requirement, below is that's app link which is available on Playstore. [Phone INFO ★Samsung★](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You can not get that info, AFAIK. I tkink that there is a lot of "System info" apps in Google Play, and none of them shows that information.

Personally, I don't think that info like "phone color" or "headset connect counter" (!) is stored in the phone.